# Asp.Net 5 API documentation generator

Tags: documentation, asp.net-core

I need to generate the documentation of my Api created with asp.net 5 beta6.

Is there something similar to [PHPDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) for asp.net 5 (vNext)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you want to use the [SwashBuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle) NuGet package (You want the pre-release ones). This adds [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) to your ASP.NET 5 site. Swagger not only produces documentation, it also allows you to test your API.